# Python - Connect to a remote host from tkinter Script

Tags: python, linux, tkinter, conda

I am writing a tkinter script which accepts a linux command from the UI. Once the submit button is clicked,I  want to run this command that I got from the UI on a remote linux server and collect the output and display on the Tkinter window.

Regarding the tkinter parts, i am doing fine. the problem is when I wanna execute this command on the remote server and collect the output.
I will be running my program in a Virtual Environment of **Conda**

on a small research on google the most common solution I saw was the usage of fabric as shown here in this [link](http://www.linux.org/threads/remote-commands-via-fabric-part-1-hello-linux-org.4685/)
other solutions which I saw was the usage of plink and popen.

But I am not clear as to where I will mention the host name and password  to connect to the remote server with any of the solutions stated above. How I will send my command and receive the output back to my tkinter flow. Is there way that I can understand if the command I executed failed because of some reason?

Any help on this will be appreciated! thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found the solution i was looking for.. may be i did not read the docs which i surfed before properly..
here its

```
def connect():
    print "starting to connect"
    env.host_string = 'vpnuser@10.0.0.70'
    env.password = "vpnuser "
    run("ls -lrth")
```

put this in a fabfile.py file and run it like this
fab -a connect

That is it !

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [`host_string`](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.10/usage/env.html#host-string) to dynamically specify what the destination is. Change it before executing commands.

An example would be:

```
from fabric.api import run, env

env.host_string = 'user@host.com'

def ls():
    run("ls")
```

Comment: hey Reut! mind showing me a short example? also where to specify the password of the remote server which i am about to connect.. this is the thing specifically asked in my question ;)